# the dataframe has a column names on every each of rows..how to change it into one row of name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

So I created a dataframe but it has column name on every each of rows...like this one:[image: 1]

could anyone help me to change into this way? shown as pic 2 [image: 2]
Thank you sooooo much!!!

revised: 
the original data is: `[{'complete': True, 'volume': 116, 'time': '2020-01-17T19:15:00.000000000Z', 'mid': {'o': '1.10916', 'h': '1.10917', 'l': '1.10906', 'c': '1.10912'}}, {'complete': True, 'volume': 136, 'time': '2020-01-17T19:30:00.000000000Z', 'mid': {'o': '1.10914', 'h': '1.10922', 'l': '1.10908', 'c': '1.10919'}}, {'complete': True, 'volume': 223, 'time': '2020-01-17T19:45:00.000000000Z', 'mid': {'o': '1.10920', 'h': '1.10946', 'l': '1.10920', 'c': '1.10930'}}, {'complete': True, 'volume': 203, 'time': '2020-01-17T20:00:00.000000000Z', 'mid': {'o': '1.10930', 'h': '1.10931', 'l': '1.10919', 'c': '1.10928'}}, {'complete': True, 'volume': 87, 'time': '2020-01-17T20:15:00.000000000Z', 'mid': {'o': '1.10926', 'h': '1.10934', 'l': '1.10922', 'c': '1.10926'}}, {'complete': True, 'volume': 102, 'time': '2020-01-17T20:30:00.000000000Z', 'mid': {'o': '1.10926', 'h': '1.10928', 'l': '1.10913', 'c': '1.10920'}}, {'complete': True, 'volume': 277, 'time': '2020-01-17T20:45:00.000000000Z', 'mid': {'o': '1.10918', 'h': '1.10929', 'l': '1.10913', 'c': '1.10928'}}, {'complete': True, 'volume': 103, 'time': '2020-01-17T21:00:00.000000000Z', 'mid': {'o': '1.10927', 'h': '1.10929', 'l': '1.10920', 'c': '1.10924'}}, {'complete': True, 'volume': 54, 'time': '2020-01-17T21:15:00.000000000Z', 'mid': {'o': '1.10926', 'h': '1.10926', 'l': '1.10910', 'c': '1.10912'}}, {'complete': False, 'volume': 15, 'time': '2020-01-17T21:30:00.000000000Z', 'mid': {'o': '1.10913', 'h': '1.10918', 'l': '1.10912', 'c': '1.10913'}}]`

And I use this to print out the dataframe:

```
for x in data['candles']:
    result=({'time':x['time'],'open':float(x['mid']['o']),'high':float(x['mid']['h']),'low':float(x['mid']['l']),'close':float(x['mid']['l'])})
    datas=pd.DataFrame(result,index=[0]).set_index('time')
    print(datas)
```

Comment: how are you printing it ? what code u have ?

Comment: Thank you Krishnan, I just revised the question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply series to mid column and concat:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'complete': True, 'volume': 116, 'time': '2020-01-17T19:15:00.000000000Z', 'mid': {'o': '1.10916', 'h': '1.10917', 'l': '1.10906', 'c': '1.10912'}}, {'complete': True, 'volume': 136, 'time': '2020-01-17T19:30:00.000000000Z', 'mid': {'o': '1.10914', 'h': '1.10922', 'l': '1.10908', 'c': '1.10919'}}, {'complete': True, 'volume': 223, 'time': '2020-01-17T19:45:00.000000000Z', 'mid': {'o': '1.10920', 'h': '1.10946', 'l': '1.10920', 'c': '1.10930'}}, {'complete': True, 'volume': 203, 'time': '2020-01-17T20:00:00.000000000Z', 'mid': {'o': '1.10930', 'h': '1.10931', 'l': '1.10919', 'c': '1.10928'}}, {'complete': True, 'volume': 87, 'time': '2020-01-17T20:15:00.000000000Z', 'mid': {'o': '1.10926', 'h': '1.10934', 'l': '1.10922', 'c': '1.10926'}}, {'complete': True, 'volume': 102, 'time': '2020-01-17T20:30:00.000000000Z', 'mid': {'o': '1.10926', 'h': '1.10928', 'l': '1.10913', 'c': '1.10920'}}, {'complete': True, 'volume': 277, 'time': '2020-01-17T20:45:00.000000000Z', 'mid': {'o': '1.10918', 'h': '1.10929', 'l': '1.10913', 'c': '1.10928'}}, {'complete': True, 'volume': 103, 'time': '2020-01-17T21:00:00.000000000Z', 'mid': {'o': '1.10927', 'h': '1.10929', 'l': '1.10920', 'c': '1.10924'}}, {'complete': True, 'volume': 54, 'time': '2020-01-17T21:15:00.000000000Z', 'mid': {'o': '1.10926', 'h': '1.10926', 'l': '1.10910', 'c': '1.10912'}}, {'complete': False, 'volume': 15, 'time': '2020-01-17T21:30:00.000000000Z', 'mid': {'o': '1.10913', 'h': '1.10918', 'l': '1.10912', 'c': '1.10913'}}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = pd.concat([df, df['mid'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1, sort=False)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you BERA! Do you know reason why “ for loop” make the dataframe like that?